# Fill NaN information with value in same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am wondering that is there have any faster method to solve this problem without using for loop?

The input dataframe look like this:

```py
    0    1    2    3    4    5    6   
0   x    x    1   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1   x    y    1   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2   y    y    4    4    4    4    4
3   y    z    5    2    7    4    0  
4   x    x   NaN   5    7    4    9
5   x    y   NaN   9    4    5    10
```

I want the output look like this:

```py
    0    1    2    3    4    5    6   
0   x    x    1    5    7    4    9
1   x    y    1    9    4    5    10
2   y    y    4    4    4    4    4
3   y    z    5    2    7    4    0
```

`col0` & `col1` are some information. These two columns will not have NaN and is unique if we take them as one information.

This dataframe might be very large, and I don't know where the data missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If need first non `NaN` values per groups use [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby([0,1], as_index=False).first()
print (df1)
   0  1    2    3    4    5     6
0  x  x  1.0  5.0  7.0  4.0   9.0
1  x  y  1.0  9.0  4.0  5.0  10.0
2  y  y  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0   4.0
3  y  z  5.0  2.0  7.0  4.0   0.0
```

---

```
print (df)
   0  1     2     3     4    5     6
0  x  x  10.0   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN
1  x  x  20.0   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN
2  x  x   1.0   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN
3  x  y   1.0   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN
4  y  y   4.0   4.0   4.0  4.0   4.0
5  y  z   5.0   2.0   7.0  4.0   0.0
6  x  x   NaN   5.0   7.0  4.0   9.0
7  x  x   NaN  50.0  70.0  4.0   9.0
8  x  y   NaN   9.0   4.0  5.0  10.0
```

If more rows without NaNs per groups is possible some data lost:

```
df1 = df.groupby([0,1], as_index=False).first()
print (df1)
   0  1     2    3    4    5     6
0  x  x  10.0  5.0  7.0  4.0   9.0
1  x  y   1.0  9.0  4.0  5.0  10.0
2  y  y   4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0   4.0
3  y  z   5.0  2.0  7.0  4.0   0.0
```

Possible solution with custom function:

```
def f(x):
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({y: pd.Series(x[y].dropna().values) for y in x})
    return (df1)

df = df.set_index([0,1]).groupby([0,1]).apply(f).reset_index(level=2, drop=True).reset_index()
print (df)
   0  1     2     3     4    5     6
0  x  x  10.0   5.0   7.0  4.0   9.0
1  x  x  20.0  50.0  70.0  4.0   9.0
2  x  x   1.0   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN
3  x  y   1.0   9.0   4.0  5.0  10.0
4  y  y   4.0   4.0   4.0  4.0   4.0
5  y  z   5.0   2.0   7.0  4.0   0.0
```

Comment: Thanks! You help me a lot:)